# Where exactly we are hiding implementation details in Java (Abstraction)

Tags: java, class, oop, abstract-class, abstraction

```
public abstract class abs {
    abstract void dance();
}
```

This abstract class was extended by `Outer` class.

```
public class Outer extends abs {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Outer o = new Outer();
        o.dance();

    }

    @Override
    void dance() {

        System.out.println("dancing from abstract class");
    }
```

I didn't specify any implementation details of `dance()` method in abstract class but defined the `dance()` method in `Outer` class i.e implementation details are revealed in derived class (`Outer`). We gonna run this program from `Outer` class. So, where exactly we are hiding implementation details from the user? Where is abstraction achieved?

Comment: In some other class: `public whatever(abs d);` can receive your an instance of Outer, and make it dance, without even knowing there is such a thing as your Outer class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11966068/5602214

Comment: Hiding implementation details = using of **supertype** which can be **interface**, **abstract class** or **class**. Example: `abs a = new Outer();` i.e. concrete class `Outer` is hidden in `abs` supertype. Why would you do that? You will find the answer in [What does it mean to program to an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

Answer (score 0):

It is hidden in the sense that you will, probably, work with the abstraction in your application and `wire` the concrete classes when needed according to the context where you are in.

The key idea is that it is important that an object can do something, how it does it is not necessairly important always. A direct consequence on working with the abstraction is that you can easily change the implementation `under the hood` without any side-effects whatsoever.

For instance consider a `sort` operation of a language. When you call sort with on collection. in general, all you want is to sort the collection, about how it is done is not always important.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case here, nothing is hidden, because you are using `Outer` as the type of the variable here:

```
Outer o = new Outer();
```

To hide the implementation of `Outer` behind `abs`, you can write a method that returns `abc`, that actually returns an `Outer`:

```
public static getAbc() { return new Outer(); }
```

Now in your `main` method:

```
// you should probably put your main method in another class, together with getAbc
// this way the code can better demonstrate how to hide implementation.
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    abc o = getAbc();
    o.dance();
}
```

Now your `main` method does not know anything about `Outer` It only knows about `abc`.

You can study examples in the JDK as well. For example, the `Stream` interface has a method called `of` that returns a `Stream`:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("Hello", "foo", "bar");
```

What it actually returns is a `ReferencePipeline.Head` after calling a bunch of methods in `Arrays` class and `StreamSupport` class. See the hiding here? You, as the user of the interface, don't need to know what `of` actually returns. You just need to know that it returns something that can perform all the operations specified by the `Stream` interface.

One benefit of this is that if one day `StreamSupport`'s code are changed to return something else, your code will still work and compile because it is guaranteed that whatever it returns, will implement the `Stream` interface so has all its capabilities.